# Kendo Grid JSON datasource binding

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I seem to be having an issue trying to bing my JSON result to my Kendo UI grid

This is my JSON result I get back from my web service:

```
"{
    "Data":[{
        "ModifiedBy":"Joe Blogs",
        "ModifiedDate":"2015-04-27T00:00:00",
        "Name":"One",
        "Number":"201504260952",
        "Status":"Draft",
        "Id":3
    },
    {
        "ModifiedBy":"Joe Blogs",
        "ModifiedDate":"2015-07-08T11:04:00",
        "Name":"fdasfdsa",
        "Number":"20150708110209",
        "Status":"Draft",
        "Id":17},
    {
        "ModifiedBy":"Joe Blogs",
        "ModifiedDate":"2015-07-09T08:44:00",
        "Name":"Two",
        "Number":"20150709084329",
        "Status":"Draft",
        "Id":20
    }],
    "Groups":null,
    "Total":3
}"
```

This is my Grid and data source set up:

```
$(function () {
        var myGrid = $("#myGrid");
        myGrid.kendoGrid({
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true,
                buttonCount: 5
            },
            columns: [{
                hidden: true,
                field: "Id"
            },
            {
                headerTemplate: ""
            },
            {
                title: "Status",
                field: "Status"
            },
            {
                title: "Number",
                field: "Number"
            },
            {
                title: "Name",
                field: "Name"
            }]
        });

        var myDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/somewhere.svc/Data",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: 'Data',
                groups: 'Groups',
                aggregates: 'Aggregates',
                total: 'Total',
                model: {
                    id: 'Id',
                    fields: {
                        Id: { type: 'number' },
                        Status: { type: 'string' },
                        Number: { type: 'string' },
                        Name: { type: 'string' },
                        ModifiedBy: { type: 'string' },
                        ModifiedDate: { type: 'date' }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverGrouping: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            serverFiltering: true
        });

        myGrid.data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(myDataSource);
    });
```

When the page loads I can see that I get the above JSON but I don't get any rows displayed in the grid.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: it does work if i use dummy data [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/OJEzo). Instead of set the grid first then datasource,can you try initializing the datasource first then referencing datasource from the grid ?

Comment: @machun Whilst setting the grid first wasn't the issue the example you set up made me realise that my JSON that I was getting back was a string and not an object hence the issue. Thanks for the help. Great to know about the Kendo UI Dojo as well. Great help thanks again

Comment: @user2595610, That was still a good question.  I think you could write and accept your own answer to let other users know how you solved this issue.